# subtracting the eigenvalue matrix from the original transformation of a 2x2 hit's the other eigenvalue proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the question:
Prove that if λ, μ are real eigenvalues of a 2 × 2 matrix, then any nonzero column of the matrix A − λI is an eigenvector for μ.
I assume A is the linear map for which these are the eigenvalues. I am pretty lost after playing around with a generalized 2x2 for awhile

Comment: What do you mean by "non-zero column"?

Comment: your guess is as good as mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $A-\lambda I$ as an augmented matrix $[x,y]$. So, the statement "any nonzero column of the matrix $A − \lambda I$ is an eigenvector for $\mu$" means that $Ax=\mu x$ and $Ay=\mu y$ (regardless of whether $x$ or $y$ is zero). In turn, this means $A[x,y]=\mu[x,y]$, or $A(A-\lambda I)=\mu (A-\lambda I)$. In other words, what you are going to prove is that
$$
A^2-(\lambda+\mu)A + \lambda\mu I = 0,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
A^2-\operatorname{trace}(A)A+\det(A)I=0.
$$
You may verify this equality directly by explicitly calculating the LHS of $(1)$ in terms of the entries of $A$. This equality is actually a special case of [Cayley–Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Start with a matrix $ A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a && b \\ c && d \end{array}\right)$, the eigenvalues are the roots of $ (a - x)(d - x) - bc $.

We can write that better as $ x^2 - (a + d)x + (ad - bc) = 0 $, so we know $ \mu + \lambda = a + d $ and $ \mu\lambda = ad - bc $, in fact, this is just standard trace and determinant equalities.

Now suppose the first column of $ A - \lambda I $ is non zero, so we have the vector $ v = \left(\begin{array}{c}a - \lambda \\ c \end{array}\right) $

To verify it is an eigenvector, we multiply it with the matrix and get

$ Av = \left(\begin{array}{c}a(a - \lambda) + bc \\ c(a-\lambda) + cd \end{array}\right) = \mu\left(\begin{array}{c}a - \lambda \\ c \end{array}\right) $

To justify the last equality, we write

$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  a(a - \lambda) + bc &=& \mu(a - \lambda) \\
  a^2 - a\lambda + bc &=& a\mu - \mu\lambda \\
             a^2 + bc &=& a\mu + a\lambda - \mu\lambda \\
             a^2 + bc &=& a(\mu + \lambda) - \mu\lambda \\
             a^2 + bc &=& a(a+d) - (ad-bc) \\
             a^2 + bc &=& a^2 + ad - (ad-bc) \\
                    0 &=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}
$

Of course, we read that backward.

All other cases can be proved similarly, lot of algebra.